# Как преобразовать номер телефона к виду 8999999999?

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать номер телефона к виду 8999999999,
сейчас вид такой +7(344) 444-44-44.
Сделала из него такой +73444444444
следующим образом:

```
const numberValueReduced = phone => {
    return phone.replace(/-|_|\s|\(|\)/g, '');
};
```

Как теперь +7 заменить на 8 регуляркой?

Comment: Отдельно поставить еще один `replace("+7","8")`

Comment: А что должно стать с номером +375 (22) 2222222?

Comment: @Yaant, а откуда в РФ вы взяли такой номер?

Comment: А где в вопросе упоминается РФ? И потом, в РФ достаточно много граждан РБ, например.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const phone = '+7(344) 444-44-44';
console.log(phone.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^7/,'8'));
```